# fancybox compatibility with MOSS 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, fancybox, sharepoint-2007, fancybox-2

Has anyone gotten the current version of fancybox 2.1.4 (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) with jQuery 1.9.1 to work with Microsoft Office SharePoint Server (MOSS) 2007?

Seems like the out of box css/html of MOSS 2007 is interfering with the sizing and positioning calculations that fancybox/jQuery does.  The end result is a tiny fancybox (130px width).

Here is a screenshot of the issue:
[screenshot of issue http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-54-79-Images/4152.fancyboxIssueInMOSS2007.png](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-54-79-Images/4152.fancyboxIssueInMOSS2007.png)

Here is the super simple code I am doing:

MAIN PAGE:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.fancybox-2.1.4_Styles.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox-2.1.4.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    Hello from the test page!
    <a id="fancyBox1" style="display: none" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="iframeContents.aspx"></a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // show fancyBox
            $('#fancyBox1').fancybox().trigger('click');
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

IFRAME PAGE:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    Hello from the iframeContents!
</asp:Content>
```

Thanks for any and all help!

PS-By the way, fancybox works fine in SharePoint 2010.  However, I must make it work in MOSS 2007.

Comment: Check that your document has a proper `DOCTYPE` ... it seems like is running in quirks mode

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/a/15856581/1055987 and apply the `iframe preload false` workaround... it might be related

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!  Thanks JFK.

Yes, the problem was the browser (IE 10 in this case) was running in quirks mode since there was no DOCTYPE present.  After I added the DOCTYPE to the master page, fancybox works!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Side note:  having the DOCTYPE added to the masterpage actually disrupts out of box MOSS 2007 branding.  But it's ok in my case since we will be using custom branding that already does have the DOCTYPE present.  I got lucky with that one.  Thanks again for the help!